# In a stored procedure, disabling index script not effective when it is run from SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a SQL Server stored procedure which has a script inside to disable set of nonclustered indexes on a table before loading the data into.

When I manually run the procedure, the indexes are getting disabled as expected, but when the same procedure gets executed from SSIS "Execute SQL Task", the indexes are not getting disabled.

I'm wondering why? This impacts performance a lot ... Any thoughts around why the indexes are not getting disabled from SSIS?

Comment: What is the code in your Execute SQL Task?

Comment: EXEC [usp_name] followed by parameters

Comment: ....what is the code in your stored procedure?

Comment: I don't know, I just recreated the table and the issue is resolved!

Answer (score 1):

Just Recreating the table with the same script solved it!!!. The table is there for 4-5 years having weekly load. Not sure though the exact reason for the issue!

Comment: Be careful with that. Dropping and recreating the table will delete all permissions that were previously granted to that table. Did you perform an impact analysis to make sure no other user accounts or automated processes are impacted by that change?